# Pandas hasnans returns wrong value for column containing NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a DataFrame with approx. 200 columns, 7000 rows.  Column `B` consists of entirely `NaN` values, with the exception of about 400 rows in the middle.

In sum, Column B looks like this (condensed for brevity):

```
      B
 1  NaN
 2  NaN
 3   75
 4   83
 5  NaN
 6  NaN
```

However, when I write some code as follows, the `hasnans` attribute seems to have the wrong value.  Am I using the attribute incorrectly or something?

```py
df['B'].hasnans
```

returns
`False`

Edit:
Below is a small sample of a CSV file that I am importing into pandas.  The column still fails to find the NaN values.  An astute observer will notice the spaces surrounding the `B` in the column header.  That is expected and not the issue.

```
"  DATE       TIME  ","  A  ","  C  ","  B  "
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:07,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:08,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:08,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:09,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:09,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your exact df and code and returned True. In your instance they are probably NaN's as strings. Change the dtype to int and try again.

Comment: I think you meant change dtype to `float`

Comment: Yes I did, change the dtype to `float` and try again, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read your csv in, you should use the `skipinitialspace` option to remove the leading whitespace in your data. Note that since the column names are in quotes, the whitespace around those will remain

```py
# make fake csv
from io import StringIO

mock_csv = StringIO()
mock_csv.write("""\
"  DATE       TIME  ","  A  ","  C  ","  B  "
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:07,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:08,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:08,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:09,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:09,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
""")
mock_csv.seek(0)

# disregard initial whitespace
df = pd.read_csv(mock_csv, skipinitialspace=True)
assert df['  B  '].hasnans
```

See the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=skipinitialspace)

Comment: Your answer gave the most concise fix, so you get the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Considering

```
"  DATE       TIME  ","  A  ","  C  ","  B  "
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:44:36,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:07,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:08,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:08,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:09,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
12/11/2018 15:45:09,     5448,     0.00,      NaN
```

as the .csv file you are importing as pandas dataframe, you must take care of the real values you are looking for.

In fact:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=0)

df['  B  '].replace('      NaN', np.nan, inplace=True)
df['  B  '].hasnans
```

returns:

```
True
```

Comment: Your solution worked well, except in cases with different number of spaces.  I generalized it to a regex of `\sNaN` and set the regex flag and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, its showing false because `"NaN"` value in your column is `"NaN"` not `np.nan` hence that column's datatype could be 'object', I guess. So you have to convert that `"NaN"` value into `np.nan` so that column's object will be int or float as you like and hasnans will return the correct boolean value.

So first,

```
df[df["B"] == "NaN"] = np.nan #it will convert "NaN" values into np.nan
```

and now you can check NaN values using either `hasnans` or `isnull().any()`

Cheers!